# Illustrator replace stroke color of different objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, stroke, selections

I have Illustrator CS6.

Imagine a certain number of objects (here 4) with different fill and stroke colors.

How can I replace simultaneously the stroke color of all objects that have a violet stroke (there can be many and I don't want to mark them one by one) to green, without changing the fill color (if it is violet)?

So I wish that only the left two rectangles get a green stroke and that the two ellipses (especially the one with the violet filling color) remain unchanged.

[image]

Comment: If this is a situation you run into frequently, you should get into the habit of making in your swatch palette that have the *global color* option checked. Any fill or stroke that has a global swatch applied to it will update to match any changes made to the swatch itself.

Comment: @ biscuitstack: yes this problem I have often ... thank for the tip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Select a single object with the stroke color you want to change
2. *Select → Same → Stroke Color*
3. Activate the stroke in the Color panel and change the color

Comment: Great ... this is the solution, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this without the need to select any of the shapes. From the Swatches flyout menu, select Add Used Colors. This will not only create a new global color swatch for each color that is used in the current document, but it will also apply those swatches to all objects as well. You can then edit any of the global swatches (double-click on the swatch) to edit the color. Any object that uses a global swatch will automatically be updated when you edit the swatch.
So, if you want to change the color of all purple strokes, you can do it instantly simply by editing the definition of the purple global swatch.